# Increment time with 12 hour clock from AM to PM

Tags: java, date, time

I am trying to increment a time value and getting odd results:

```
 private String getNextTime(String time) {

        final int INTERVAL = 1;

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a", Locale.US);           /
        Date d = null;                                                              
        try {
            d = df.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad tee time: " + time);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                                      
        cal.setTime(d);                                                             
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, INTERVAL);                                         
        String outTime = df.format(cal.getTime());                                  
        return (outTime);                                                           
    }
```

If I input 11:59 AM the result is 12:00PM. If I input 12:59 PM I am expecting 01:00 PM, but get 13:00 PM. If I input 01:00 PM, I am expecting 01:01 PM, but get 01:01 AM. How do I get this to work correctly with a 12 hour clock?

Comment: I believe the reason this is happening is because one format specifier must take precedence over the other.  In this case the _H_, or _h_, appears to take precedence over the _a_.

Comment: Your code is basically doing what you're telling it to do - the problem is, you're format specifier is incorrect - you should also no longer be making use of `Calendar` or the `java.util` based date/time classes and instead prefer the `java.time` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat and Date are obsolete and buggy.  Use the more modern classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.US));
LocalTime ldt = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
for (int h = 1; h < 10; h++) {
    System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
    ldt = ldt.plusHours(h);
}
```

prints

```
9:00 AM
10:00 AM
12:00 PM
3:00 PM
7:00 PM
12:00 AM
6:00 AM
1:00 PM
9:00 PM
```

Default Locale will be used if not specified.  And use `"hh:mm a"` if you want leading zeros for single digit hours.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

Change:

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a", Locale.US);

to:

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);